# Objective-C: Accessing Object field within an Object

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am currently new to developing in xcode and I am wondering how to access fields of an object that is inside another object (ie. Car object inside Vehicle Object).

for my cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I am trying to access a field within my Patient Class that sits inside my Admission class. I have an array [myList] that holds admission objects and within admission objects, I have patient objects.

Here is the code where I am having a problem, within my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SimpleCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[admList objectAtIndex:row]admPatName];
    return cell;
}
```

Problem is on this line below:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[myList objectAtIndex:row]??];
```

on the ?? area, I couldn't figure out the right reference to the field.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
JR

Comment: Could you please post your Patient class from the .h file?

Comment: In objective-C objects can't directly access fields belonging to another object. (As in public C++ members).  Instead you have to send a message to the other [otherObj getFoo], or as a property otherObj.foo.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[[myList objectAtIndex:row] patient] name];
```

Or, if you prefer, like this:

```
Admission *admission = [myList objectAtIndex:row];
cell.textLabel.text = admission.patient.name;
```

I'm guessing the problem you had was that dot syntax doesn't work directly on [myList objectAtIndex:row] because the compiler doesn't know what kind of object that is.

You can usually use dot or [...] syntax interchangeably in Objective-C, so if dot syntax doesn't work, try square brackets. For what it's worth, you could get it to work with dot syntax by casting the array object, but it's a bit messy with all the brackets:

```
cell.textLabel.text = ((Admission *)[myList objectAtIndex:row]).patient.name;
```

Comment: I don't think so. Whenever I've tried it the compiler has complained with a warning like "property foo not found on object of type id" because array objects have an unspecified type.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your classes look something like this:

```
@interface Patient : NSObject {
  NSString *name;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;

@end


@interface Admission : NSObject {
  Patient *patient;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Patient *patient;

@end
```

and you have an array (admList) of Admission objects. Here's how you would access the name of the patient that's referenced by the admission with index `i` in the array:

```
[[[admList objectAtIndex:i] patient] name]
```

Alternatively:

```
Admission *admission = [admList objectAtIndex:i];
cell.textLabel.text = admission.patient.name;
```

<strike>or:</strike>

```
cell.textLabel.text = [admList objectAtIndex:i].patient.name;
```

Comment: If you try that last one I think you'll find it doesn't work.

Comment: @NickLockwood: you're right, it turns the compiler treats that as an error and not a warning as I initially thought.

Comment: This should work though: [[admList objectAtIndex:i] patient].name

Comment: It should, as long as the patient property is unique to the Admission class. Otherwise, you should get at least a warning.